# add opacity to entire page except one widget

Tags: flutter

How can I apply opacity to the entire page except an `IconButton` in `appbar` in flutter? Something like [flutter_showcaseview](https://pub.dev/packages/showcaseview)

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Opacity(
      opacity: 0.5,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: ...,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: ...
      ),
    );
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Would you try making custom appbar?
I made a some sample. I hope it help you.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appTitle = 'Opacity Demo';
    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

// The StatefulWidget's job is to take data and create a State class.
// In this case, the widget takes a title, and creates a _MyHomePageState.
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

// The State class is responsible for two things: holding some data you can
// update and building the UI using that data.
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // Whether the green box should be visible
  bool _visible = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(
            70,
          ),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            height: 70,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget> [
                AnimatedOpacity(
                  opacity: _visible ? 1 : 0.2,
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                  child: AppBar(
                    title: Text('Title'),

                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                        onPressed: () {}
                      ),
                  ),
              ]
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ),
      body: AnimatedOpacity(
          opacity: _visible ? 1 : 0.2,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          child: Center(
        child: Container(
            width: 200.0,
            height: 200.0,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // Call setState. This tells Flutter to rebuild the
          // UI with the changes.
          setState(() {
            _visible = !_visible;
          });
        },
        tooltip: 'Toggle Opacity',
        child: Icon(Icons.flip),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could achieve such a feat:

Rows, columns and flexes can have an `Expanded` child. It receives a flex ratio (which, according to the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html), determines "how a flexible child is inscribed into the available space"), and a `child` of itself.

Say our "real" content is in a vertical layout, like a `Column`. We could, then, wrap our content with a `Stack` (documentation [here])(https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html), which enables us to add content **above** our app's original content, and add a new `Column` on top of it.

It would have mainly two `Expanded` children and a placeholder. The placeholder will ensure the one widget has no opacity laid out above it, and the `Expanded` children could paint an opaque color to the rest of the screen.

Here's a code to ilustrate the idea:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 50.0,
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget> [
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 240.0,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 80.0,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text("Your content here"),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 240.0,
                  color: Colors.red,
                )
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.black54,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 80.0
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.black54,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```